# How to return a largest number in a string java

Tags: java

say that I have a couple of numbers in a string: 
String line = "564 33 654 8321 15";
And now want to find the largest number inside this string.
the lab give me the algorithm help for getLargest() method:

```
largest = really small number;
while(there are more number to check)

{num= get current number
if(num > largest)
largest=num
}
```

could somebody help me to figure out how to do this "getLargest" method?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried and why it doesn't work, and not just pseudocode

Comment: I agree with peeskillet here. You already have pseudocode down (which is a very good start). If you haven't actually put it into code, start one step at a time, like just extracting the numbers out from the string to begin with. Being able to break a program down into small, manageable pieces is a very important skill, which is why a lot of us haven't posted solutions; it would rob you of important experience.

Comment: I just want to know how would I access each number in a string ?

Comment: Okay, that's a start. You might want to edit the question to reflect that; as is the question is written as if you want us to do all of the work from beginning to end. On top of that, the reason why we voted to close the question was that this site isn't really for "give me the code to do it" questions so much as "why does this piece of code that I have to do something not work in this specific way"

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

- Split the string into parts; e.g. read the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for `String.split(...)`.
- Convert strings to integers; e.g. read the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) for `Integer.parseInt(...)`.
- The rest is a loop and some simple logic.

If you have problems understanding those hints, ask using 'comment'.

<sup>(I'm not going to give you example code because I think you will learn more by doing the work yourself.)</sup>

Comment: You could use StringTokenizer instead of String.split

Comment: @MistressDavid As noted in the javadoc for `StringTokenizer`, using `.split()` is the preferred method and use of `StringTokenizer` in new code is discouraged. It's a legacy thing.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you won't learn anything from getting your homework done by people online. You might learn something from it either way and try yourself next time. I have included comments in the solution.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //The line is a String, and the numbers must be parsed to integers
    String line = "564 33 654 8321 15";

    //We split the line at each space, so we can separate each number
    String[] array = line.split("\\s+");

    //Integer.MIN_VALUE will give you the smallest number an integer can have,
    //and you can use this to check against.
    int largestInt = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    //We iterate over each of the separated numbers (they are still Strings)
    for (String numberAsString : array) {

        //Integer.parseInt will parse a number to integer from a String
        //You will get a NumberFormatException if the String can not be parsed
        int number = Integer.parseInt(numberAsString);

        //Check if the parsed number is greater than the largestInt variable
        //If it is, set the largestInt variable to the number parsed
        if (number > largestInt) {
            largestInt = number;
        }
    }

    //We are done with the loop, and can now print out the largest number.
    System.out.println(largestInt);
}
```

Comment: 1) Please do not encourage students to be lazy.  2) Even if the OP does not copy your solution, he / she has not had to go through the learning process of looking up the javadocs and working it out the solution for him / herself.

Comment: Duly noted, you make a good point. My first post :)